# Alternative DNS Record to set SPF

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I have a server provider that hosts my domain (e.g: mycompany.org) but unfortunately I can't access the DNS records and they will not change it.

Now I have a problem with email filters and would like to set up a SPF for the domain (mycompany.org), but no access to the DNS.

Is it possible to set a SPF records in some other company, service, server etc and propagate it ? Set up my own DNS ?? Suggestions and ideas welcome :)

Thank you

J.

PS: I can't move the domain name / DNS to another provider :(

Comment: You _must_ move the domain and DNS to another provider.

Comment: Please elaborate on why you can't? If you truly own the domain, no one can stop you.

Comment: I use a product from STRATO company called managed server, it is a sort of web hosting. I discovered that if a domain is no associated with the managed server the server will reply with an server error configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The company that owns/manages your DNS is doing that. You won't be able to create a new one and go around that. Internally to your company if you have an internal DNS server you will. Externally on the internet though, the company that hosts your DNS owns it.

If you setup your own DNS, you are going to need to take control of the name and point it to your new DNS server. Sounds like you can't do that because you don't have control of it.